# How can I allow the user to drop several seperate pins on bing map wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, cloud, bing-maps, pins

I would like the user to add several pins to a map to represent tents or people using map1_Hold event.
How can I do this and store each dropped pin location on a cloud later(windows azure)?

Comment: Can you be more specific in your requirements. Are you wanting to add a pin each time someone taps a location? What have you tried? There are lots of ways to store information online. Again be more specific in your actual requirments and explain what you've tried.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot use a pin to represent a tent. This would fail certification for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To drop pins on a map you can do the following: (here `map` comes from my .xaml page where map is the name of the Map: `<my:Map Name="map" ...`

Setting up the event handler

```
map.Hold += new EventHandler<GestureEventArgs>(dropPin_Hold);
```

and the actual event handler:

```
void dropPin_Hold(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    // drop a pin at the Held location
    GeoCoordinate pinLocation = new GeoCoordinate();
    // gets the dropped position
    pinLocation = map.ViewportPointToLocation(e.GetPosition(map));

    newLocation = new Pushpin() { Location = pinLocation, Name = "Tent's name" Content = "new tent" };
    map.Children.Add(newLocation);

    // save the newLocation however you want

}
```

Multiple holds will result in multiple pins being displayed on the map.

You might also want to check out map.Tap

Comment: Excuse my delayed response, I have had to replace my computer.

Comment: I am currently saving user pin to xml but am having trouble retrieving this location info on restart.